# Getting weird question marks after decoding UTF-16-encoded hex bytes

Tags: c#

I'm reading a hex byte array from a file using an instance of the `BinaryReader` class, and I need to decode it from UTF-16. From what I know, I need to do this using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte[] array)`.

This is what my code looks like:

```cs
public static string ReadHex(string path, Int32 startOffset, Int32 endOffset, bool decode, bool utf16)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException($"Could not find a file in path {path}");
    }

    string result = "";
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path));

    for (int i = startOffset; i < endOffset; i++)
    {
        br.BaseStream.Position = i;
        bytes.Add(br.ReadByte());
    }

    br.Close();
    if (decode && utf16)
    {
        result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
    else if (decode)
    {
        result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
    else 
    {
        foreach (byte b in bytes)   
        {
            result += b.ToString("X2");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It reads the given hex offsets provided by the parameters and decodes them if wanted. The UTF-8 part works perfectly, giving me valid decoded strings. But my issue is with the UTF-16 part.
This is the data that is read from the file:

```
4D 00 6F 00 6A 00 61 00 6E 00 67 00 20 00 41 00 42
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In theory, this is what should be outputted:
`Mojang AB`

It kinda works, but with one oddity, this is what is outputted when writing the string that the method returns:

`Mojang AB                                                      ?`

These question marks appear on anything that's UTF-16 I put into the method. I don't understand why they appear, as the data that was passed into `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte[] array)` does not contain anything past the string it's supposed to contain, and is made up of zeroes (`00`). Anyone have an idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, is that a hex editor view of the file, or that the text content of the file? If it's just a hex editor view of the file, then I expect you simply need to open a `StreamReader` with the correct encoding.

Comment: Those strings [are different](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fOtxaM): `"a"` and `"a\0"`. The question is here why original file contains `00`? If you can't change that, then you have to remove `\0` from result or `00` bytes from input somehow.

Comment: I think you are just reading the internal buffer of the Stream  (overreading the file) by setting the position like that, either way its an unusual approach

Comment: @John this is a hex editor view of the file. I'll look into it, thanks.